# Flot Chart from PHP

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, flot

I'm trying to have a flot chart with values from a database.  How I have it now, the chart only plots 1 datapoint.  How can I get it to plot the rest of the data from the array?  I'm trying to plot the total count of agents that were entered on each date.  **var data2 will be for agents lost**

```
<?php

      foreach($mysqli->query('SELECT COUNT(*), agent_date_entered, agent_id 
      FROM agents GROUP BY agent_date_entered 
      ORDER BY agent_date_entered') as $row) {

        $count[] = $row['COUNT(*)'];
        $agent[] = $row['agent_id'];
        $date[] = $row['agent_date_entered'];

      }
?>

<script>
    var data, data1, options, chart;
    var data1 = [ <?php echo json_encode($count); ? > , < ? php echo json_encode($date); ?> ];
    var data2 = [];

    data = [{
        data: data1,
        label: "Agents Gained",
        lines: {
            show: true
        },
        points: {
            show: true
        }
    }, {
        data: data2,
        label: "Agents Lost",
        lines: {
            show: true
        },
        points: {
            show: true
        }
    }];
    options = {
        legend: {
            position: "nw"
        }
    };
    $(document).ready(function () {
        chart = $.plot($("#placeholder"), data, options);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Does the query return the correct results when execute in the DB?

Comment: Yes it does.  `print_r ($count);` also displays the correct result

Comment: Okay, so this sounds like a JS/flot issue, not a mysql or PHP issue.

Comment: What types are `$count` and `$date`? The code looks like you only have one count-date-pair which will give only one datapoint. For a larger graph you need an array of date-count-pairs.

Comment: The $count is to total the number of records for each $date.  I wasn't sure if I did that correctly, but when I print_r ($count); it does give me the number of results I was expecting.  I've got some sample data in the database and it gives Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 1 ) for print_r ($count);.  If I change the date it retrieves only one result.  When I do echo json_encode($count); echo json_encode($date); it outputs ["1","1"]["2018-08-01","2018-09-03"].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of the links in one of the comments to [Data format](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md#data-Format) and [Time series data](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md#time-series-data), I found the answer I was looking for.

Just in case anyone else is having this issue, here is how I got it to work.  First, I changed the date in the sql statement to read:  `(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(agent_date_depart)*1000) AS date`.  Then I encoded it when I set the variable `$depart = json_encode(floatval($row['date']));`.  To make it so it's not a huge number on the x-axis and displays as a date, I set the x-axis like this:  `xaxis: {mode: "time", timeformat: "%Y/%m/%d"},`.  You can even set the date format in the tooltip by using tooltipOpts like this:

```
    tooltipOpts: {
        content: function (label, x, y) {
            var date = new Date(+x);
            var tooltip = '<h4>' + label + '</h4><ul>';
            tooltip += '<li>Date ' + date.toLocaleDateString() + '</li>';
            tooltip += '<li>Total Count: ' + y + '</li></ul>';
            return tooltip;
        },
```

The easiest way I found to get the data to display inside the chart, I put the sql statement inside the data variable like this:

```
        var d2 = [

<?php

         $sql = "SELECT COUNT(agent_id), (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(agent_date_depart)*1000) AS date FROM agents
          WHERE agent_date_depart BETWEEN '$bdatecy' AND '$edatecy'
          GROUP BY agent_date_depart ";
          $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);
           while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    $agent = $row['COUNT(agent_id)'];
    $depart = json_encode(floatval($row['date']));

    echo "[".$depart.", ".$agent."],";
  }

?>

  ];
```

Hope this helps and I wanted to say thank you again for those links.

Answer (score 0):

Your data format is not what Flot requires. You need something like

```
[[1, 1533081600000], [1, 1535932800000]]
```

(or `[[1533081600000, 1], [1535932800000, 1]]` if you want the dates on the x axis).
The numbers likes `1535932800000` are JavaScript timestamps. You also need the option `mode: 'time'` on the axis with the date/time values.

For more info see the documentation under [Data format](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md#data-Format) and [Time series data](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md#time-series-data).

Comment: Thank you very much for those links that was very helpful.